# Is this the wrong way of handling array of objects from api call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to store a array of names from a json response containing an array of objects.

For some reason the printing array will have nothing inside.Is this the correct way of doing it.
Its not working for some reason otherwise no errors.

also the forEach is loop not even running once i tested it.

```
useEffect(() => {
  
    instance.get('/')
    .then(function (response) {
      // handle success
      //console.log(response);
      console.log(response.data);
      (response.data).forEach(newValue=>
        {
          setArray(oldArray => [...oldArray,newValue.name])
        }
      )
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
    })
    .then(function () {
      console.log("printing array 1",Array);
      // always executed
    });
    
    if(Array)
    console.log("printing array 2",Array);
    
  },[]);
```

Comment: Is `setArray` a state variable?

Comment: @mchowdam yes its a state variable

Comment: looks ineffcient

Comment: @TheFool How will you  do it?

Comment: something like this maybe: `setArray(oldArray.concat(newArray.map(({name}) => name])))`. So that you call only once setState and avoid spreading too often. You could also use a simple for loop to push into the old array before you call setArray, that would be even better. For loops are good.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setArray([...oldArray, ...response.data?.map(item=>item.name)]);
```

Rather than updating your state for every item in the new array, just get all the `name` props as an array from the new array using `map` and then use the spread operator to combine both new and old arrays.